# Customizing "network unreachable" msg in user authentication implemented using spring-security + Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-security

Any way of customizing network unreachable error message for user authentication implemented using spring-security + Hibernate?

Current Message that appears in login page when network goes down:

**Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection**

I just need to customize this error message and show a simple message.

Comment: This link help will you figure out how to generate custom messages for spring. http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/display-custom-error-message-in-spring-security/

Comment: Thanks Aakash... I found out the way of overriding spring error messages with the link provided. However in my case the exception is being thrown from Hibernate and JDBC connection. Coudn't find any spring error message "key" to override such errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [Spring MVC exception handler](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

```
@ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) {
    logger.error("Request: " + req.getRequestURL() + " threw " + exception);

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.addObject("exception", exception);
    mv.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
    mv.setViewName("error");
    return mv;
}
```

And then simply map the `error` view to a customized error page.